# Parsing JSON with Python and Returning All Fields that Match

Tags: python, json

I have parsed a JSON file and now I want to create a new Python Script that uses a for loop to loop through an unknown amount of environments input and return all that match the JSON.

```
{
    "Environments" : [
    {
        "Dev": [
            "111",
            "222"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Qa": [
            "333",
            "444"
        ]
    },
    {
        "prod": [
            "555",
            "666"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is my JSON. I know how to parse that and return the fields/accounts I want. What I am after is how to return an unknown amount of accounts I may need for huge pieces of JSON. Thank you.

HERE IS WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR

```
def jsonimporter(file_path , env_to_return):
    a = open(file_path,"r") #opens and sets the file to read

    data = a.read()         #sets variable to read function
    # print(data)

    json_data = json.loads(data) #loads the json data and stores it in json_data variable


    for env in json_data["Environments"]: # for loops that sets env to json_data and passes it a param of "Environments" from the read json file
        if env_to_return in env:
            return env[env_to_return]
        # else:
        #      print('Not Found')
    return "not found"
```

That is the initial function I created that opens and read the json as well as loads/parses it.

```
def get_multiple_envs_using_jsonimporter(file_path , env_list):
    var1 = jsonimporter(file_path,env_list[0]) #calls the jsonimporter, sets it to a variable and gives it two params
    var2 = jsonimporter(file_path,env_list[1])
                                                #same as above but, with different params

    full_list=[] #sets the full_list variable to a list

    full_list.append(var1) #appends the data inside var1 to the list

    full_list.append(var2) #appends the data inside var2 to the list


    return full_list        #returns the full list
```

Here is my second function that I use to call two JSON environments that I have appended to a list

I call this one using:

```
from helper_scripts import get_multiple_envs_using_jsonimporter

env_list = ["Dev","prod","Qa","TRex"]
var3 = get_multiple_envs_using_jsonimporter("test2.json",env_list)
```

Now I am trying to create a function that can call any amount of user input environments

Comment: So and what have you tried so far? When you parse your JSON your can iterate through your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate an unknown amount of key's like this:

```
env_list = ["Dev","prod","Qa","TRex"]

for items in iter["Environments"]:
  for key in items:
     if key in env_list:
        print(key, items[key])

#('Dev', ['111', '222'])
#('Qa', ['333', '444'])
#('prod', ['555', '666'])
```

IIUC this should return all keys in the env_list:

```
env_list = ["Dev","prod","Qa","TRex"]

def get_user_ids(env_list, hm):
   build_keys=[]
   build_return=[]
   for items in hm["Environments"]:
      for keys in items:
         build_keys.append(keys)
   for key in env_list:
     if key in build_keys:
       for items in hm["Environments"]:
          if key in items.keys():  
              build_return.append(items)
   return build_return
```

Comment: I like this idea as it is very simplistic. However, I need to create a function for it to call later based on user input.

Comment: Could be a stupid question but, why put [key] like that in the print call?

Comment: Could you let me know if the second part is what your trying to do. I don't know what's in the second file, so i'm wondering, if this is on the right path and if not, maybe an idea as to what i would need to change to match what your looking for.

Comment: That looks really great but, I would only have one file. Also, just curious but why use hm as a parameter?

Comment: just to pass in the json to the function, rather than reading it globally, Either way works though, it's not necessary, just a matter of how to deal with the json.

Comment: ok thank you for clarification. Let me add some local variables and I will re-upload the working code. Thank you for your help. Stay tuned.

Comment: Just a bit confused on the hm parameter part. I don't understand what I should pass it when I call it here.

Comment: Ah, I was passing in the variable you have at the very top of the post for your question. I can rewrite it using a global if you'd like

Comment: No I get that. And sorry for the late response huge storms here. But, i'm asking for the hm param what am I to pass that?